# Update field and value mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

Let say I have a collection. I want to change the field name and value in the whole collection like this

Current:

```
language:"en",
documentId:"123"
```

Desired:

```
  languages:["en"],
  documentIds:["123"]
```

db.foo.... Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Query

- empty filter `{}` and updateMany to update all collection
- you can use "$field" to refer to filed and and array literals
- and `$unset` to remove the old fields

*pipeline update requires MongodDB >= 4.2

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t2hgoYxRftc)

```js
updateMany({},
 [{"$set": {"languages": ["$language"], "documentIds": ["$documentId"]}},
  {"$unset": ["language", "documentId"]}])
```

Comment: It really helped me a lot. Thank you so much

Comment: read mongodb documentation, its very good with examples, you can see the reference, has all the operators